# xml file saving, grandchildren nodes in own line in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, file, newline

i started using xml in a vb.net project and i have one problem when trying to save it to a directory, i have the root and  its children nodes  well formated (new line for each one) but each 'grandchild' node is in the same line as it's parent(the child of the root), and i need the xml file to be very well formated and human readable, is there a way to make the file saving use a new line for each node.

Example:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
Dim root As XmlElement
root = doc.CreateElement("ROOT")
doc.AppendChild(root)

For i = 1 To 20
    Dim child As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("CHILD")
    child.InnerText = "child" + i.ToString
    child.SetAttribute("attributename", i.ToString & "1")
    child.SetAttribute("attributename2", i.ToString & "2")
    root.AppendChild(child)

    For k = 1 To 20
        Dim grandchild As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("GRANDCHILD")
        grandchild.InnerText = "grandchild" + k.ToString
        grandchild.SetAttribute("attributename3", k.ToString)
        grandchild.SetAttribute("attributename4", (k * 2).ToString)
        child.AppendChild(grandchild)
    Next
Next
doc.Save("d:\test.xml")
```

I found that it's all about the inntertext, once a node has an innertext, its children nodes are all in the same line, is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting your attributes without actually adding them. You need to add the attributes and set their values.

```
Dim att As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("attributename")
att.Value = i.ToString() & "1"
child.Attributes.Append(att)
att = doc.CreateAttribute("attributename2")
att.Value = i.ToString() & "2"
child.Attributes.Append(att)
root.AppendChild(child)
```

Also you can't have inner text for the child tag if you want there to be line breaks in-between the children. That is just how .NET writes its XML docs.

Comment: actually, i did put a value in them, the second parameter does that, and the xml file contains the attributes+values

Comment: So your schema calls for a parent node with inner text and children nodes? Let me play around with that, it's been awhile since I've worked with xml.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to set inner text of `<CHILD>` last after all `<GRANDCHILD>`s has already been added, for example :

```
For i = 1 To 20
    Dim child As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("CHILD")
    'Do not set inner text here'
    'child.InnerText = "child" + i.ToString'
    child.SetAttribute("attributename", i.ToString & "1")
    child.SetAttribute("attributename2", i.ToString & "2")
    root.AppendChild(child)

    For k = 1 To 20
        ........
        ........
    Next
    'set innertext (as TextNode) to child node after grandchilds already appended'
    Dim value As XmlNode = doc.CreateTextNode("child" + i.ToString)
    child.AppendChild(value)
Next
```

The output is something like this :

```
<ROOT>
  <CHILD attributename="11" attributename2="12">
    <GRANDCHILD attributename3="1" attributename4="2">grandchild1</GRANDCHILD>
    ........
    ........
    <GRANDCHILD attributename3="20" attributename4="40">grandchild20</GRANDCHILD>child1</CHILD>
    ........
    ........
</ROOT>
```